# How to get content on web page include content in javascript like see on browser

Tags: php, curl

i need to get contents on web page and read it via cURL on php,but contents not include data on javascript any body can help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by "include data on Javascript" exactly. The fact that external JS is not loaded? Or that it is not executed?

Comment: yes,JS is not loaded. example http://trailers.apple.com/trailers/independent/stone/ I can't get contents on View Trailers (2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possibel. 
A web page with embedded JavaScript is actually a program. CURL gives you the program's source code (HTML and JavaScript), but doesn't run that program. To run a page's embedded JavaScript you need (1) a JavaScript interpreter, and (2) the Document Object Model (DOM) for the page. Browsers have these, but PHP does not. People are working on PHP versions of these, but developing these are big tasks. If this is what you need, you might skip PHP and instead look at writing C++ code using [WebKit](http://webkit.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possibe you can do it through a phantomjs browser that loads the page
process its javascript and then you can retrieve dynamically rendered content as well.
have a look at this link, it may help you.

https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs