# Get processed content of URL

Tags: php, javascript, curl, xmlhttprequest, domdocument

I am trying to retrieve the content of web pages and check if the page contain certain error keywords I am monitoring. (instead of manually loading each URL everytime to check on the sites, I hope to do this programmatically and flag out errors when they occur)

I have tried XMLHttpRequest. I am able to get the HTML content, like what I see when I "view source" on the page. But the pages I monitor runs on Sharepoint and the webparts are dynamically generated. I believe if error occurs when loading these parts I would not be able to flag them out as the HTML I pull will not contain the errors but just usual paths to the webparts.

cURL seems to do the same. I just read about DOMDocument and I was wondering if DOMDocument process the codes or does it just break the HTML into a hierarchical structure.

I only wish to have the content of the URL. (like what you get when you save website as txt in IE, not the HTML). Or if I can further process the HTML then it would be good too. How can I do that? Any help will be really appreciated. :)

Comment: To be clear do you want to remove the html tags from a web and get only the remaining data?

Comment: Hi Nish, I wish to get the processed content, like after the javascript loaded and the content generated. Not a view source with the javascript and functions still there then stripped off their tags. I should put up an example to better explain myself :)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to strip the HTML? It's better to use it!

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$oDom = new DomDocument();
$oDom->loadHTML($data);

// Go through DOM and look for error (it's similar if it'd be
// <p class="error">error message</p> or whatever)
$errors = $oDom->getElementsByTagName( "error" ); // or however you get errors
foreach( $errors as $error ) {
    if(strstr($error->nodeValue, 'SOME ERROR')) {
        echo 'SOME ERROR occurred';
    }
}
```

If you don't want to do that, you can just do:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if(strstr($data, 'SOME_ERROR')) {
    echo 'SOME ERROR occurred';
}
```

Comment: Hi Dow! Thanks for answering! I believe I have to strip the HTML because the site I cURL on is a sharepoint site and places likely with errors are going to be dynamic content. View source isn't showing the content within. So if my check is based on this string, I think I wouldn't be able to catch the errors.

Comment: View source isn't showing the content within? So the content is produced from Javascript? In that case, it is going to be a lot harder..

Comment: erm yes. Content is producted from Javascript. Is there any way I can retrieve the content?

Comment: Not really, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922228/how-to-get-content-on-web-page-include-content-in-javascript-like-see-on-browser Are you sure it is js? There might be a way to retrieve the error via XML or HTTP code? SharePoint should provide a way to do that. Perhaps ask your question again, specifically about SharePoint?